# Why does Apache POI destroy the format of my Excel file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm writing a program which should put some date into an Excel sheet (.xls). The Excel sheet is a given template which I have to use.

My problem now is that when I change a cell value with the code below the format of the sheet is completely lost. The backround colour, buttons, pictures, ... are gone and also the size of the cells is changed.

I have tried to use `createCell()` instead of `getCell()` but this didn't help.

```
public static void write() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(...);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
    HSSFCell cell = null;       

    cell=sheet.getRow(4).getCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(55);

    fis.close();

    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
    workbook.write(outFile);
    workbook.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```

I hope someone can give me a hint what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. All what your code does is setting a new cell value in cell `C5` of the second sheet in the workbook. This is what thousands of `apache poi` users are doing without any issues thousands times. If that code destroys your sheet, then the template must be the reason. So no help possible without having the template.

Comment: The template is this one: 

http://www.skvb.de/fileadmin/user_upload/documents/classic/dkb120Wurf800x.xls


Could the protection of some cells be the problem?

Comment: The problem lies somewhere in the `VBA` module named `VBA-Modul`. If I am removing this module from the template file, then the problem disappears. And even if I am creating a new module having the same code and then removing the module named `VBA-Modul`, the problem disappears. So it has nothing to do with the code but with how the binary representation of the module named `VBA-Modul` is stored in the file. Seems it is somehow corrupted.